# UNION three different SELECTs in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, select, union

I have this MYSQL table named people with the columns: id|firstname|lastname|birthdate|phone.

I am quite new to MYSQL and I'm trying to UNION several SELECTs so that the result will look in the following way:

- only the first 20 results must be shown
- the first SELECT criteria is by the combination firstname+lastname+birthdate: WHERE (birthdate="1980-01-01") AND ((firstname LIKE "%john%") AND (lastname LIKE "%smith%"))
- the second SELECT criteria is by the combination firstname+lastname: WHERE (firstname LIKE "%john%") AND (lastname LIKE "%smith%")
- the third SELECT criteria is by phone: WHERE phone="0123456"
- the output result must in fact have 3 columns: order|id|type; where "order" and "type" are alias columns
- the exported ids must be unique: if the same id results from all the 3 SELECTs (or from more than one SELECT), then it must appear only once in the output table
- the column "order" must have the value 1 for the results of the first SELECT, 2 for the 2nd SELECT and 3 for the last SELECT
- if the same id value results from more than one SELECT, then its row must have the highest order value; where the highest order posible is 1, from the first SELECT
- the alias column "type" must work like this: if an id results from the 1st SELECT, it's type value is "~firstname+lastname+birthdate~"; if an id results from the 2nd SELECT, it's type value is "~firstname+lastname~"; and finally if an id results from the 3rd SELECT, it's type value is "~phone~"
- if the same id value results from more than one SELECT, the value on the "type" alias column must be a concatention between the SELECTs where that id was found (for example, if the same id resulted in all 3 SELECT queries then the value on the "type" column would be "~firstname+lastname+birthdate~~firstname+lastname~~phone~")

Is it possible to achieve such an output?

Comment: Please, give your best attempt: SQL tables structure + SQL query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something using CASE statements. I think you'll get into a mess with union statements, because of your order type statement. Hopefully I've understood what you're after - it's much easier if you post sample data! Anyway, even if this doesn't do exactly what you want, you get the idea....

[EDIT] I don't think you need the distinct, but I don't think it hurts, either...

```
 SELECT DISTINCT 
        CASE WHEN birthdate='1980-01-01' 
                AND firstname LIKE '%john%' AND lastname LIKE '%smith%'
             THEN 1
             WHEN firstname LIKE '%john%' AND lastname LIKE '%smith%'
             THEN 2
             WHEN phone='0123456'
             THEN 3
        END AS outputorder, -- avoid confusion of using an SQL keyword as a column name,
           id,

           CONCAT(
              CASE 

     WHEN birthdate='1980-01-01' 
            AND firstname LIKE '%john%' AND lastname LIKE '%smith%'
            THEN CONCAT('~',firstname,'+',lastname,'+','~')
          END ,

         CASE WHEN firstname LIKE '%john%' AND lastname LIKE '%smith%'
             THEN CONCAT('~',firstname,'+',lastname,'~')
         END ,
         CASE WHEN phone='0123456'
              THEN CONCAT('~',phone,'~')
         END 
       ) -- end the concat
       AS outputtype
FROM

     mytable
WHERE
   ( birthdate='1980-01-01' 
   AND firstname LIKE '%john%' AND lastname LIKE '%smith%')
OR
   (firstname LIKE '%john%' AND lastname LIKE '%smith%')
OR
    phone='0123456'
ORDER by 1,2 LIMIT 20
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I did something like this and it worked just fine:

```html
SELECT MIN(`ord`) AS `order` , `id` , GROUP_CONCAT(`spec`) as `type` FROM (
SELECT "1" AS `ord` , `id` , "~firstname+lastname+birthdate~" AS `spec` FROM `people` WHERE (`birthdate` = "1986-04-02") AND (`lastname` LIKE "%smith%") AND (`firstname` LIKE "%john%")
UNION
SELECT "2" AS `ord` , `id` , "~firstname+lastname~" AS `spec` FROM `people` WHERE (`lastname` LIKE "%smith%") AND (`firstname` LIKE "%john%")
UNION
SELECT "3" AS `ord` , `id` , "~phone~" AS `spec` FROM `people` WHERE (`phone`="0123456")
) final
GROUP BY final.`id`
ORDER BY `order` ASC 
LIMIT 20
```

Thanks to mlinth for the alternative though...